# Calculating the Start Date of the Last Quarter

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm looking to calculate the start date of the last quarter based on the current date.

Where

```
Q1 = Jan-Mar
Q2 = Apr-Jun
Q3 = Jul-Sep
Q4 = Oct-Dec
```

Hence, if the current date is `8th Jan 2018`, the function would return the date `1st Oct 2017`.

I have written the following code, however, this seems clunky and inelegant, and I have a feeling that there may be a better way to write it (for example, using `dateadd`).

```
Function LMLastQuarterStart() As Date
    Dim mo As Integer
    Dim yr As Integer: yr = Year(Date)
    Select Case Month(Date)
    Case 1 To 3: mo = 10: yr = yr - 1
    Case 4 To 6: mo = 1
    Case 7 To 9: mo = 4
    Case Else: mo = 7
    End Select
    LMLastQuarterStart = DateSerial(yr, mo, 1)
End Function
```

I would appreciate any advice/suggestions offered, thanks.

Comment: Replacing instructions separators (`:`) with actual newlines and indenting the `Case` statements would go a long way towards fixing the clunkiness IMO. That said, this looks like it would make a good post on [codereview.se], assuming the code works as intended.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, Thank you for your valuable feedback - I actually wasn't aware of the existence of Code Review, but it looks like a fantastic resource. Regarding the indentation: I don't tend to indent `Case` statements because they don't have a corresponding `End Case` and therefore I find that the indentation looks unequal.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, Great idea to use an Optional reference date parameter! Would there be a way to evaluate `Date()` as the default value for such parameter (within the parameter list), or would the parameter need to be tested for null inside in the function and then assigned the current date? BTW, your Rubberduck add-in looks awesome!

Comment: If you make the parameter a `Variant` then you can test for `IsMissing` (it wouldn't be `Null`). Optional params default values need to be compile-time constant, so a `Date` call wouldn't work. You can then also test with `IsDate` to make sure you're looking at an actual `Date` (a `Variant` could be anything). ...and thanks!

Comment: @Mat'sMug That works very well - I've not previously used `IsMissing` so that's a new one for me - thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @WonkotheSane Since OP desires a different approach, and not review and improvement of the existing code, I disagree with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you're looking for, with the `DateAdd`, is the following:

```
Public Function LastQuarter(theDate As Date) As Date
    LastQuarter = DateAdd("q", DatePart("q", theDate) - 2, DateSerial(Year(theDate), 1, 1))
End Function
```

Explanation:

`DateSerial(Year(theDate), 1, 1))` returns the first quarter of the current year.

`DateAdd("q", DatePart("q", theDate), ThatDate)` adds the current quarter, returning the next quarter (e.g. quarter 1 -> quarter 2). So the -2 substracts two quarters.

About clunkyness: this function may be shorter and possibly include less operations, but it's harder to understand. That may or may not be relevant.

And about parameters: I have made it take a date, to both make it easy to test and to let you keep it variable. You can do with that what you will.

Thanks to [Gustav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3527297/gustav) for making the suggestion to use `DatePart` instead of `Format`

Comment: Many thanks Erik, that's great. Thank you also for your explanation and feedback - I agree that the `DateAdd` solution isn't immediately readable compared with my simplistic approach. Nevertheless, your use of the `Format` function within the `DateAdd` function is clever, thank you.

Comment: You could also use _DatePart_ which returns a numeral: `DateAdd("q", DatePart("q", theDate), ThatDate)`.

Comment: @Gustav Thanks for that suggestion. I've implemented it in the answer. It's certainly preferential, because it avoids a Variant(String) to Variant(Long) cast, and thus should decreases the required processing time.